# How to Gain Visibility and Optimize Quota Usage in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, optimization

How do I go about optimizing my Google App Engine app to reduce instance hours I am currently using/paying for?

I have been using app engine for a while and the cost has been creeping upwards.  I now spend enough on GAE to invest time into reducing the expense. More than half of my GAE bill is due to frontend instance hours, so it's the obvious place to start.  But before I can start optimizing, I have to figure out what's using the instance hours.

However, I am having difficulty trying to determine what is currently using so many of my frontend instance hours.  My app serves many ajax requests, dynamic HTML pages, cron jobs, and deferred tasks. For all I know there could be some runaway process that is causing my instance usage to be so high.

What methods or techniques are available to allow me to gain visibility into my app to see where I am using instance hours?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question, but I will offer a few pointers.

First, examine App Engine's console Dashboard and logs. See if there are any errors. Errors are expensive both in terms of lost business and in extra instance hours. For example, tasks are retried several times, and these reties may easily prolong the life of an instance beyond what is necessary.

Second, the Dashboard shows you the summary of your requests over 24 hours period. Look for requests with high latency. See if you can improve them. This will both improve the user experience and may reduce the number of instance hours as more requests can be handled by each instance.

Also look for data points that surprise you as a developer of your app. If you see a request that is called many more times that you think is normal, zero in on it and see what it is happening.

Third, look at queues execution rates. When you add multiple tasks to a queue, do you really need all of them to be executed within seconds? If not, reduce the execution rate so that the queue never needs more than one instance.

Fourth, examine your cron jobs. If you can reduce their frequency, you can save a bunch of instance hours. If your cron jobs must run frequently and do a lot of computing, consider moving them to a Compute Engine instance. Compute Engine instances are many times cheaper, so having such an instance run for 24 hours may be a better option than hitting an App Engine instance every 15 minutes (or even every hour).

Fifth, make sure your app is thread-safe, and your App Engine configuration states so.

Finally, do the things that all web developers do (or should do) to improve their apps/websites. Cache what can be cached. Minify what needs to be minified. Put images in sprites. Split you code if it can be split. Use Memcache. Etc. All of these steps reduce latency and/or client-server roundtrips, which helps to reduce the number of instances for the same number of users.

Comment: All of the things you mentioned are reasonable, but how do I know which ones will have an effect and which ones are just best practices? Ideally, I'd like to have some evidence before I start playing with it. I guess I'm just stuck with the logs and the 24 hour request summary. Basically, what I'd like is a much more detailed version of the 24 hour request summary.

Comment: Details are not going to help you, because the relationship between individual requests and instance hours is too complex. You may have two requests in the first 15 minutes resulting in 2 instances, and then 1000 requests in the next 15 minutes all served by a single instance. If you have 3 visitors per day, you can figure it out, but  even at a few hundred visitors it becomes nearly impossible to model. Optimize the most frequent requests or the worst offenders.

Comment: And that's my question: how do you find the worst offenders? The 24 hour request summary is far too coarse.

Comment: If you have thousands of requests, then 24 hours is plenty of time to see the averages. If you have very few requests, then, by definition, there is very little benefit in optimizing them.

Comment: Not really. The list just gives you the endpoint. All Taskqueues are lumped into the `deferred` endpoint. Depending on the parameters, the endpoint may do wildly different things.

Comment: There is a wealth of information in the request logs.  Analyze that, look at the request duration and the most common requests.  If the traffic pattern is normal, then you will need to focus on the longer running requests.  Do some analysis of your application run time characteristics then you will have the evidence you need to work out what areas you need to focus on.

Comment: I agree there is a wealth of information in the logs. So is my only recourse to go through each log one by one? There must be a more efficient way that can make this process faster/tractable.

Answer (score 0):

Besides code changes (all suggestions in the other answer are good) you need to look into the instances over time graph.
If you have spikes and constant use, the instances created during the spikes wont go to sleep because appengine will keep using them. In appspot application settings, change the "idle instances" max to a low number like 1 (or your actual daily average).
Also, change min latency to a higher number so less instances will be created on spikes.
All these suggestions can make an immediate effect on lowering your bill, but its just a complement to the code optimizations suggested in the other answer.

Comment: I think both answers misunderstand the question. It wasn't "how do I reduce the app engine bill," but rather, "how do I determine what requests/taskqueues/parameters are eating up my app engine quota." The tools that app engine provides seem insufficient.

Comment: you CAN with the existing tools, but not in a straightforward way. You can chart RAM over time or instances over time and determine when they go over. You can use the latency table at the bottom of the overview page to tell what calls are taking longer. Longer calls means an increased chance that another instance will be started. I have an app with daily spikes of thousands of users entering in small windows of 5 minutes and never goes over a single instance because of optimizacions based on both answers. Before it was creating 6 instances on its peaks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my other answer was about optimizing at the settings level.
To trace the performance at a granular level use the new cloud trace relased today at google i/o 2014.
http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2014/06/cloud-platform-at-google-io-enabling.html